# I want to reply to my post back url

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, postbackurl

I had a GPT site. When users complete an offer on my offer walls, the site sends a postback request to my site so that I can credit my users. After crediting I have to reply them with '1'. I wrote Response.write("1") in my event. Everything is going fine, and the script is well. The points are also crediting. But they are not getting my reply and sending me request once again. Please, help me how to send a reply to that post back URL using ASP.Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `HttpClient`, `WebClient`, or `HttpWebRequest` classes to send HTTP requests, in decreasing order of convenience.

Comment: Can you please give solution in detail?